# Bulk rename files in Windows, to sequentially generated new names

Tags: windows-10, batch-rename

I need help bulk-renaming some file names. I have around
300 directories. All files are Word `.docx` files, and need to remain Word files after renaming.

In each folder I have between 1 and 20 files (***never*** more than 26). 
I need to take them in some order (ideally alphabetic by their current name)
and rename them to follow this pattern:

```
Example A.docx
Example B.docx
Example C.docx
    etc.
```

I cannot use external software, just the terminal.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to go through each folder, and then, for the first file, give it the name `Example A`, the second file `Example B`, etc.? What order should be applied? What should happen if there are more than 26 files? What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Have you looked into the use of the forfiles command in the command line?

Comment: Research on "*piping commands thru a `FOR /F` loop*". You'll want to use the `DIR /S /B` command maybe and don't forget to use `"TOKENS=*"` or maybe `"DELIMS="` to remove space as a limiter for the command output or whatever. quick example `for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /s /b "<folderPath>"') do echo "%~a"` use the `REN` command accordingly and research "*using for loop "variable substitutions"*" too. Quick thought starting points....

Comment: @slhck Indeed, the first file would be Example A, the second - Example B, and so forth. There are never more files than letters in the alphabet. So, I have around 300 folders, and renaming everything by hand has been nightmarish. I tried the built-in Windows bulk-rename but it gives them numbers+copy in the file name, which doesn't work for me. Most of the advice is not applicable for me, as I need a space (and not underscore_) between "Sample" and the letter. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, that makes it clearer. Please [edit] your question to make it clearer, otherwise you risk having it closed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: (1) I edited your question.  Please review and fix any mistakes I made.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) You say “I have used a suggestion from below comments which works; the only issue is the computer does not recognise the format of the files.” (2a) You should ***say*** what you have tried.  Copy the script into your question (giving credit to the source, of course).  (2b) I assume that you’re talking about [harrymc’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1350663/150988#1350697).  [robinCTS posted a comment an hour ago](https://superuser.com/q/1350663/150988#comment2026072_1350697) explaining how to address that.  Have you tried it?  What happened?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PowerShell script that does what you ask :

```
$letters = [char[]]([char]'A'..[char]'Z')
$directoryName = $null
$count = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path "your folder path" -File -Recurse | 
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($directoryName -eq $null -or $directoryName -ne $_.DirectoryName) {
      $directoryName = $_.DirectoryName
      $count = 0
  }
  $newname = "Example " + $letters[$count++] + ".docx"
  Rename-Item $_.fullname $newname
}
```

Take a backup first.

Comment: Thank you! I have run the script but it does not change any of the names. The name of the folder is "AsReceived". Is there any part of the script you shared that I need to modify any given folder/path?

Comment: Yes, the part that is cunningly hidden as `"your folder path"`.

Comment: Amazing, now it really works. Just last question - the files I am renaming are in Word format but after renaming, the system does not recognize them anymore as such. Any remedy for this?

Comment: @Densetsu You need to add the `.doc` extension, i.e `$newname = "Example " + $letters[$count++] + ".doc"`.

Comment: Correct. Are all the files `.doc` or `.docx`? Or might both types be mixed?

Comment: If they are all the same type, just modify the script as above. Otherwise, the script needs to be improved a bit.

Comment: The files are docx, I had tried that but didn't think to put the quotation marks. THANK YOU! It works perfectly now, and you have saved me hours of work. I wish there would be someone teaching such tricks to the non-techies. And thanks to the kind soul who edited my original post, now it really does make more sense.

Comment: I have edited your post and my answer in view of our discussion. There is an enormous amount of info to find if you wish, by searching for example "PowerShell tutorial".